# List of ArrayList being altered when it's not supposed to

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, element, addition

(kb is a list of arraylists)

I am currently trying to add elements from kb.get(i) into arraylist path, although they are also being added to the first arraylist found in kb, when this is not intended.

How kb is initialized:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> kb = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanLines.hasNextLine()) { 
            edge = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(scanLines.nextLine().split(" ")));
            System.out.println(edge);
            kb.add(edge);
        }
```

How paths are initialized:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> allPaths = new ArrayList<>();
for (ArrayList<String> line : kb) {
        if (querySubConcept.equals(line.get(0))) { //Adding all edges which have the query's sub-concept
            allPaths.add(line);
        }
    }
```

Problem is here

```
if (!checker) {
   if (!path.get(path.size() - 2).equals("IS-NOT-A") || 
          !querySuperConcept.equals(superConcept)) {
                path.add(kb.get(i).get(1));
                path.add(kb.get(i).get(2));
                superConcept = kb.get(i).get(2);

                if (querySuperConcept.equals(superConcept))
                    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you add more code ? How path is initialised ? how kb is initialised ans so on...

Comment: @CodeScale added some code

Comment: `allPath` and `path` ??? both correct ?

Comment: allPaths is another list of arraylists, path is each arraylist in allPaths done by for(ArrayList<String> path : allPaths)

Comment: It looks like `allPaths` and `kb` share the inner `ArrayList` objects, so if you modify `path` (which is presumably one of the ´ArrayList` objects from within `allPaths`, that also affects `kb`, since it contains the same object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** You are adding the reference of an existing `ArrayList`.

**Solution:** You need to add a copy of the `ArrayList`.

Do it as follows:

```
for (ArrayList<String> line : kb) {
    if (querySubConcept.equals(line.get(0))) { //Adding all edges which have the query's sub-concept
        allPaths.add(new ArrayList<>(line));
    }
}
```